# How to make custom widget/component in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Let say I want a container with this style -> rounded shape and with border.

Should I create a theme for Container?
Or should I create my custom widget/component?

My main concern here is not to repeat everything so I'm thinking about this 2 possibilities.

Which one more recommended?

Kind Regards

---

And why people down voted my question. I really don't know :(

Comment: use `DecoratedBox` for example?

Comment: @pskink DecoratedBox will certainly do but my concern actually how not to repeat every time I use Container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create your widget, which extend `Widget`

It can be `StatelessWidget`

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //... return your container here
  }
```

or `StatefulWidget`

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyWidget(this.child);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: widget.child, ...)
    //... return your container here
  }
```

Comment: So would be better mmake custom widget rather than applying theme to Container? Still looking how to apply theme at container so to determine which one better

Comment: I tried this but now says named parameter child is not defined where ordinary Container would have child

Comment: There are no strictly rules about using custom widget or something else. It's only about clearance and readability of your code. I'd prefer to use custom widget - it's more conveniently for me. And I didn't understand question about child - it's not required field for `Container`

Comment: Hi Andrey I've updated the question regarding the child attribute issue hope you could help. Thanks.

Comment: It seems, that you don't understand some basic principles of flutter development. `MyWidget` doesn't have `child` field, so what are you trying to do? I've updated the answer - added `child`. And you strongly need to learn flutter tutorials to avoid such problems in future

Comment: Ok Thanks. Yes I need to learn a lot. I'm pushed to deliver full blown e-commerce app within 2 months with flutter which is totally new to me. So please forgive me.